# How to do this layout? (breaking to new line, centered)

Tags: html, css

```
#container
{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
}

.box
{
    display: inline;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

<div id="container">
<div class="box"><img src="http://developer-static.se-mc.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/12/ScaleImages.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="http://developer-static.se-mc.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/12/ScaleImages.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="http://developer-static.se-mc.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/12/ScaleImages.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="http://developer-static.se-mc.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/12/ScaleImages.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="http://developer-static.se-mc.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/12/ScaleImages.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="http://developer-static.se-mc.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/12/ScaleImages.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="http://developer-static.se-mc.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/12/ScaleImages.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VfKa4/

this is I have so far. I want to achieve this:

### [image]

[image]

---

[image]

according to the number of blue box, only 3 may go to a line. The other goes to new line, but have to be centered. But I dont know how to do the margin, because no left-right margin is needed, still there has to be distances from each other

Comment: blue squares are divs or imgs inside div ?

Answer (score 1):

Add `width:400px` to your container (this will snugly fit three 100px images with 50px margins between them), and add the following rule:

```
.box:nth-child(3n+1) {margin-left:0}
```

Note also that to use `display:inline-block`, you cannot have any spaces between the elements, as this will mess up your layout.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VfKa4/1/)

Comment: it is not work if you add one more div in it , i have tested your fiddle

Comment: [With 1 more div](http://jsfiddle.net/VfKa4/9/), and [with 2 more divs](http://jsfiddle.net/VfKa4/10/) - works fine for me!

Answer (score 1):

I think `display:inline-block` is what you are after.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/VfKa4/6/)**

**CSS**

```
* {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container
{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: green;
    font-size:0;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}

.box
{
    display: inline-block;
    width:33%;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: please check this, you will realize what the error is :)))

Answer (score 0):

```
.box{
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This aligns items to the center. You can also set a margin value by changing the 0.

eg: `margin: 20px auto;`

Comment: interestingly, "margin: 20px auto;" has no effect

Comment: That's because they're not `block` elements. This answer is wrong ;)

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code...
try changing  "display: inline;" to "display: inline-block;"

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">
    <center>
<div class="box"><img src="http://developer-static.se-mc.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/12/ScaleImages.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="http://developer-static.se-mc.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/12/ScaleImages.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="http://developer-static.se-mc.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/12/ScaleImages.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="http://developer-static.se-mc.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/12/ScaleImages.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="http://developer-static.se-mc.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/12/ScaleImages.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="http://developer-static.se-mc.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/12/ScaleImages.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></div>
<div class="box"><img src="http://developer-static.se-mc.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2012/12/ScaleImages.jpg" width="100" height="100" /></div>
    </center>
</div>
```

Comment: thats not valid code :) (if somebody votes it down, thats not me)

Comment: <center> tag is deprecated